# Distinct Join in Nhibernate

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate

I want two columns from two different tables using join. I am getting duplicate values. I tried `.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.DistinctRootEntity`) and `.SetResultTransformer(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer())` but nothing helped me. In profiler i am getting query like:

```
SELECT job1_.DeptName as y0_, this_.refDeptId as y1_ FROM [Emp] this_ inner join [Dept] job1_ on this_.refDeptId=job1_.DeptId
```

I want query for distinct values.like: `SELECT distinct  job1_.DeptName as y0_, this_.refDeptId as y1_ FROM [Emp] this_ inner join [Dept] job1_ on this_.refDeptId=job1_.DeptId`
My query in nhibernate is:

```
IList  ListOfElements=  (session
  .CreateCriteria(typeof(EmpModel))
   .CreateCriteria("objEmpDeptId1", "job",NHibernate.SqlCommand.JoinType.InnerJoin)
  .SetProjection( a_ProjectionList).List());
```

Please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Is your a_list something like below (with aliases in case you want to Transform to DTO) ?

```
Projections.Distinct(Projections.ProjectionList()
    .Add(Projections.Property("DeptName ").As("BeanDeptName"))
    .Add(Projections.Property("refDeptId ").As("BeanDeptId"))
```